# Transition List Item Scrolling - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKLYg/).

List item that appears on clicking the `up` and `down` arrows.

When I click on it. It appears instantly which I don't want it to be like that.

I wanted to add a transition to it but I don't have any clue whether to apply it on a `li` or `a` tag.

Besides I'm here hiding and revealing `li` items on click. But I need the `transition` like when I click on the `up` arrow, I want the hidden element to push the active element downwards and vice versa.

Someone help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozgureffe/kKLYg/18/)
you may check it out.

```
var
    cur = 2,
    $container = $('.dropdown-container'),
    $ul = $('.dropdown'),
    $ul_length = $('.dropdown li').children().length,
    $up = $('.up'),
    $down = $('.down'),

    changeLi = function (cur) {
        var $cur_li = $('.dropdown li:nth-child(' + cur + ')');
        $('.current_selected').removeClass('current_selected');
        $cur_li.addClass('current_selected');

        $container
            .height($cur_li.outerHeight())
            .width($cur_li.outerWidth());

        $up.offset({
            left: ($container.outerWidth() - $up.outerWidth()) / 2
        });

        $down.offset({
            left: ($container.outerWidth() - $down.outerWidth()) / 2
        });

        $ul.animate({
            top: -$cur_li.position().top
        }, 200);

    };

$up.on('click', function () {
    cur--;
    if (cur < 1) {
        cur = 1;
        return false;
    }
    changeLi(cur);
});

$down.on('click', function () {
    cur++;
    if (cur > $ul_length) {
        cur = $ul_length;
        return false;
    }
    changeLi(cur);
});

changeLi(cur);
```

Comment: You've removed all the `hide` class and used `animate` and position property right?

Comment: yess.. It also supports long and multiple lines now. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozgureffe/kKLYg/23/)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. By the way what is `--` and `++`

Comment: increases or decreases a numeric variable one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add animatation like slideUp, slideDown etc.

```
var cur = 2;

$('.up').click(function() {
    if(cur <= 0) return;
    var last = cur;
    cur --;
    $('.dropdown li').eq(last).hide(500).addClass('hide');
    $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).show(100).removeClass('hide');
});

$('.down').click(function() {
    if(cur >= $('.dropdown li').length - 1) return;
    var last = cur;
    cur ++;
    $('.dropdown li').eq(last).hide(500).addClass('hide');
    $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).show(100).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i add `slideUp` or `slideDown`.